# Customize border line of bootstrap nav-tabs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs, border

How to customize the colour of the borders of nav-tabs which is by default light grey?
I could change the colour content div:
http://jsfiddle.net/cjz9dyen/

I tried that:

```
.nav-tabs > li.active > a {
    border-color: #d45500;
}
```

But it adds a border on the bottom.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Override the `border-bottom-color` too:

```
.nav-tabs>.active>a, .nav-tabs>.active>a:hover, .nav-tabs>.active>a:focus {
    border-color: #d45500;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
.nav-tabs {
   border-bottom: 1px solid #d45500;
}
```

http://www.bootply.com/gjjXWz6eOZ

Comment: For me (bootstrap 3) only the bottom border gets changed, the others still look the same. Weird.

Comment: @Sam same for me, did you find any solution?

Comment: No, sorry. I ended up creating something completely different instead.

Answer (score 2):

**For Bootstrap 5:**

```
.nav-tabs a.nav-link.active,
.nav-tabs a.nav-link.active:hover,
.nav-tabs a.nav-link.active:focus {
    border-color: #d45500;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
.nav-tabs, .nav-tabs a.nav-link {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d45500;
}
```

Comment: Works in Bootstrap 5.2, just make sure to change 'a' for 'button' if your setup uses buttons instead of links. Thanks!